# Vagrant Up loads with Hyper-v provider in Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox

When running vagrant up it loads with  `Bringing machine "default" up with "hyperv" provider` In Windows 10 64-bit after installing Vagrant 1.7.4 and VirtualBox 5.1.6.

The PATH variable is pointed to `C:\ProgramFiles\Oracle\VirtualBox` only. Hyper-V is disabled in my machine.

How to make VirtualBox as the default provider?

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

to make sure it spins up a VM with virtual box provider. vagrant has a variable name `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` which you can use to default your provider so in your case it must be set up with `hyperv`

Comment: Im unable to find the variable name `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` in environment Variable list

Comment: hum ... run `vagrant up --provider virtualbox` should spin the VM for virtualbox

Comment: It throws an error message that `Vagrant supports 5.0 Version of VirtualBox provider`

Comment: I have upgraded the Vagrant version to 1.8.5, Now it uses virtualbox as default provider

Comment: Now Getting the Different Error during vagrant up . Unable to mount the shared folder

`chown: /vagrant: Invalid argument`

Comment: please post your Vagrantfile -